# Maui - Using DataTriggers to change ImageButton visibility

Tags: xaml, maui

I have a dotnet Maui app and what I am trying to do is use DataTriggers to show/hide "trashIcon" when "addImage" has or has not source binding. If there is no source binding for "addImage" then "trashIcon" should be IsVisible = False. If there is a binding for "addImage" then "trashIcon" should be IsVisible = true.

How do I do this? Here is what I have attempted so far.

ViewModel Class

```cs
public partial class AddViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string imagePath;
// ...
    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task SelectPicture()
    {
        // Ask for permission for the user to select an image.
        if (PermissionStatus.Granted == await PermissionService.CheckAndRequestPhotosPermission())
        {
            var fileChosen = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
            {
                PickerTitle = "Select an image.",
                FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Images
            });

            if (fileChosen != null)
            {
                ImagePath = fileChosen.FullPath;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml Code of "addImage"

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<VerticalStackLayout
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <ImageButton
        Source="attach_image.svg"
        Aspect="AspectFit"
        Command="{Binding SelectPictureCommand}"
        MaximumHeightRequest="100"/>
    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <ImageButton
            Aspect="AspectFit"
            Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
            BorderColor="DarkSlateGrey"
            BorderWidth="2"
            MaximumHeightRequest="200"
            x:Name="addImage"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            />
        <ImageButton
            Aspect="AspectFit"
            Source="empty_trash.svg"
            MaximumHeightRequest="50"
            x:Name="trashIcon">
            <ImageButton.Triggers>
<!-- See my attempts below -->
            </ImageButton.Triggers>
        </ImageButton>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</VerticalStackLayout>
<!-- ... -->
```

Attempt #1

```xml
<ImageButton
    Aspect="AspectFit"
    Source="empty_trash.svg"
    MaximumHeightRequest="100"
    x:Name="trashIcon">
    <ImageButton.Triggers>
<DataTrigger 
    TargetType="ImageButton" 
    Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference addImage}, Path=Source.Length}" 
    Value="0">
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
    </ImageButton.Triggers>
</ImageButton>
```

Result: "trashIcon" still shows if there no binding in "addImage"

Attempt #2

```xml
<ImageButton
    Aspect="AspectFit"
    Source="empty_trash.svg"
    MaximumHeightRequest="100"
    x:Name="trashIcon">
    <ImageButton.Triggers>
<DataTrigger 
    TargetType="ImageButton" 
    Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference addImage}, Path=Source}" 
    Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
    </ImageButton.Triggers>
</ImageButton>
```

Result: "trashIcon" still shows if there no binding in "addImage"

Attempt #3

```xml
<ImageButton
    Aspect="AspectFit"
    Source="empty_trash.svg"
    MaximumHeightRequest="100"
    x:Name="trashIcon">
    <ImageButton.Triggers>
<MultiTrigger TargetType="ImageButton">
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference addImage}, Path=Source}" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference addImage}, Path=Source.Length}" Value="0" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
</MultiTrigger>
    </ImageButton.Triggers>
</ImageButton>
```

Result: "trashIcon" still shows if there no binding in "addImage"

Attempt #4

```xml
<ImageButton
    Aspect="AspectFit"
    Source="empty_trash.svg"
    MaximumHeightRequest="100"
    x:Name="trashIcon">
    <ImageButton.Triggers>
<DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference addImage}, Path=Source}" Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference addImage}, Path=Source}" Value="{x:Static x:String.Empty}">
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
    </ImageButton.Triggers>
</ImageButton>
```

Result: "trashIcon" still shows if there no binding in "addImage"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you update the `Source` property? What exactly are you trying to achieve, can you give more context?

Comment: Good point @Julian. I will update my question to include more information.

Comment: It is recommended that you can change the imageButton in the code behind.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT, was coming to the same conclusion. I don't think Triggers will give me the results I am looking for. Was using this situation as an opportunity to learn Triggers but I think it's meant for something else like validation or encouraging user behavior.

Comment: The source of the ImageButton cannot be empty or null. It will be reported as an error if the source is empty.

Comment: The Source property of Image is of type ```ImageSourc```.  And ImageSource has ```IsEmpty``` Property which can be used to identify if there is a path.

Comment: You may try the following code, 

```<DataTrigger  TargetType="ImageButton"   Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference addImage}, Path=Source.IsEmpty}" Value="True">  <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" /> </DataTrigger>```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? You can ask if you have any other questions.